# Redirecting stderr to stdout as well as to stderr

Tags: bash, logging, error-handling

I usually have the following:
./myscript > myfile.log 2>&1

I want to have stderr and stdout to be written to myfile.log as well as have stderr to go "stderr" (terminal).

I was looking at tee, but tee is only for stdout.

Comment: `tee` is for any thing you can write to its standard input. The tricky thing is that most shells don't provide an operator for connecting one process's standard error to another process's standard input analogous to `|` (which connects standard output from one to standard input of another).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tee`:

```
{ ./myscript 2>&1 >&3 | tee /dev/stderr >&3; } 3> myfile.out
```

or

```
{ ./myscript 2>&1 >&3 | tee /dev/fd/2 >&3; } 3> myfile.out
```

You might also try:

```
rm myfile.out; { ./myscript 2>&1 >&3 | tee -a myfile.out >&2; } 3>> myfile.out
```

but that feels a bit kludgy.  I believe this should work as well:

```
{ ./myscript 2>&1 >&3 | tee -a myfile.out >&2; } 3> myfile.out
```

and feels slightly less like a kludge.

Comment: Can confirm first version works. I can see FD "3" is holding stdout and stderr and something is getting piped to tee, but any explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: In the first command, you redirect fd 3 to the output file.  Then you redirect fd 2 of `myscript` to go into the pipe to tee, but you don't want it intermingled with fd 1, so you redirect fd 1 to 3.  That way `tee` gets just stderr from `myscript`, writing it to both stderr and to fd 3, intermingling it with the stdout of myscript which has been previously redirected to `myfile.out`.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
$: ./myscript 2> >( tee myfile.log >&2 ) 1>&2
```

Note the space between `2>` and `>(` is required to keep the syntax unambiguous.

To prove it works as intended, put a filter on with `grep`.
(I used `ls` as a simple way to get output on both streams.)

```
$: ls -ld . bogus 2> >( tee err.log >&2 ) 1>&2 | grep foo >stdout.log
ls: cannot access 'bogus': No such file or directory
drwxr-xr-x 1 P2759474 1049089 0 Dec 15 11:19 .
```

Output from `tee` sent to `err.log` and to console stream 2, or `stderr`. Stream 1 (`stdout`) sent wherever stream 2 went, so also to `tee`, which sends all *it's* output to its own stream 2, the `stderr` of the console.

`grep` couldn't see either, because nothing comes through on stream 1, so it can't filter non-matching lines.

```
$: ls -l err.log stdout.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 P2759474 1049089 113 Dec 15 11:19 err.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 P2759474 1049089   0 Dec 15 11:19 stdout.log
```

Everything went to `tee`'s log, nothing to `grep`'s.

```
$: cat err.log
ls: cannot access 'bogus': No such file or directory
drwxr-xr-x 1 P2759474 1049089 0 Dec 15 11:19 .
```